# Find the last occurrence of an array Java?

Tags: java, loops

I'm new to Java. I would like to get the index of the last occurrence in an array using loop. However, I don't understand why I can't.

This is the array:
    {2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3}

I would like to get the index of the last 4 in it.

My code is:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] nums = {2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3};

    int pos4 = 0;
    for (int k = nums.length -1; k >= 0; k--){
        if (nums[k] == 4){
            pos4 = k;
            break;
        }
    System.out.print(pos4);
    }
}
```

The result is: 00 ??

When I change to:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] nums = {2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3};

    int pos4 = 0;
    for (int k = nums.length -1; k >= 0; k--){
        if (nums[k] == 4){
            break;
        }
    System.out.print(k);
    }
}
```

I got 65 ???

However, when I print directly from the loop I get the index correctly:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] nums = {2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3};

    int pos4 = 0;
    for (int k = nums.length -1; k >= 0; k--){
        if (nums[k] == 4){
            System.out.print(k);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example is printing from within the loop. Once the condition was met you exited the loop and never printed out the final value.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] nums = {2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3};

    int pos4 = 0;
    for (int k = nums.length -1; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (nums[k] == 4){
            pos4 = k;
            break;
        }        
    }
    System.out.print(pos4); // moved outside of loop to print final value
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3):

How about using existing methods, and not reinventing the wheel? this one-liner solves the problem:

```
Integer[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3 };
int idx = Arrays.asList(array).lastIndexOf(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is inside the loop. So it prints 0 twice, then when the result is found the break; skips over it. Try this...

```
int pos4 = 0;
for (int k = nums.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    if (nums[k] == 4) {
        pos4 = k;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.print(pos4);  // <== after loop
```